# expected class-name before '{' token, then invalid use of incomplete type 'class class_name' when pre-declaring

Tags: c++, inheritance

I'm trying to add inheritance to my objects based on SFML and I can't solve a problem with errors

```
*expected class-name before '{' token*
```

and when I try to solve it by pre-declaring my parent class I'm getting stopped by

```
*invalid use of incomplete type 'class Object'*
```

I made Rectangle and Circle class with Object as parent class

*Object.hpp*

```
#ifndef OBJECT_HPP_INCLUDED
#define OBJECT_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "../MainClass.hpp"
#include "../Data/Data.hpp"

#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

class Object
{
public:

    Object();
    virtual ~Object();

    virtual void update() = 0;
    virtual void draw() = 0;
};

#endif // OBJECTPARENT_HPP_INCLUDED
```

in Object.cpp file I only have definitions of constructor and deconstructor

*Rectangle.hpp*

```
#ifndef RECTANGLE_HPP_INCLUDED
#define RECTANGLE_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "Object.hpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "../Data/Data.hpp"
#include "../MainClass.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Object; // <--- without this line *expected class-name before '{' token*, but with it *invalid use of incomplete type 'class Object'* 


class Rectangle : public Object
{
public:

    Rectangle(/*args*/);
    virtual ~Rectangle();

    //some functions

    void update();
    void draw();

private:
    
    //some members

};

#endif // RECTANGLE_HPP_INCLUDED
```

and *Circle.hpp*

```
#ifndef CIRCLE_HPP_INCLUDED
#define CIRCLE_HPP_INCLUDED

#include "Object.hpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "../Data/Data.hpp"
#include "../MainClass.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

class Object; // <--- without this line *expected class-name before '{' token*, but with it *invalid use of incomplete type 'class Object'* 


class Circle: public Object
{
public:

    Circle(/*args*/);
    virtual ~Circle();

    //some functions

    void update();
    void draw();

private:
    
    //some members

};

#endif // CIRCLE_HPP_INCLUDED
```

I don't know what to do, I tried changing the order of all includes, removing stuff and adding it, i searched everywhere but there was no good solution. Thank you for all answers

Comment: Instead of forward declaration, have you tried `#include"Object.hpp"` in all the files that need it?

Comment: In C++ *all* symbols must be declared before they are used, otherwise the compiler doesn't know they exist and what they might be.

Comment: "I tried changing the order of all includes, removing stuff and adding it" - Programming C++ via trial and error usually doesn't work well. You have to learn the language and *know* what you are doing when writing code. Experimenting / guessing is usually futile with a language as complicated and complex as C++.

Comment: @cigien sorry it was my mistake I forgot to change ObjectParent to Object while publishing

Comment: Do `MainClass.hpp` or `Data.hpp` include any of the headers you've shown here (`Rectangle.hpp`, `Circle.hpp`, or `Object.hpp`)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm yes, MainClass includes all of them

Comment: and I see now this is the problem

Answer (score -1):

just insert ' #include "Object.hpp" ' in Circle.hpp and Rectangle.hpp and any other file like them that is using Object class:

```
#include "ObjectParent.hpp"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include "../Data/Data.hpp"
#include "../MainClass.hpp"
#include "Object.hpp"           //    <----------
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
```

Comment: Compiler for compiling which file gives this error?

Comment: Rectangle.hpp and Circle.hpp

Comment: do not compile these file directly. these files are header. compile the corresponding souce file instead . i mean   'Rectangle.cpp'   and 'Circle.cpp'.

Comment: if I understood correctly, do I have to compile these files separately, without compiling the entire program? 
When I compile Rectangle.cpp I get error from Circle.hpp, and with Circle.cpp I get error in Rectangle.hpp

Comment: NO. When You are compiling a C++ program that consist of some source files (.cpp) and some header files (.hpp) , you need to send only source files to Compiler as input. for example if your project have three files: [main.cpp, object.cpp and object.hpp ], main.cpp and object.cpp are compiler inputs:     "g++ -o app  main.cpp object.cpp"

Comment: sorry I'm a newbie, how do I do this?